# Changing position of navbar at mobile view

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I was wondering if there was a way to change the position of a navigation bar in mobile view by only using CSS3. For example instead of having the navigation bar underneath the top container in mobile view, I would like to have it fixed above the top container. I am using a wordpress theme, Thanks in advanced.
[image] The website is www.capcar.com.au

Comment: provide any jsfiddle or demo which you have tried..thank you

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention I am using a wordpress theme

Comment: then plz provide the demo or screenshot?

Comment: I have provided a link to the website and an demo of what the current mobile view looks like Thanks

Comment: sorry but i am afraid that is not possible by only css..you have to change the html but why you don't want to? as far as i can make work around is to change the position and top but its not good solution so not giving..and please decrease the logo width too as its affecting the responsiveness of site..

Comment: Thanks mate its still a work in progress. I had a feeling that might be the case and I find it really frustrating. The solution I thought of was making it position: absolute and top : 0 @media screen (max-width: 600px). I'll do my best with the logo. If you have any other suggestions They would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may try "transform" property with media rule.

Answer (score 0):

Add css :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) { 

       .navigation_menu {
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
    .header_section {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        color: #99ca00;
        padding-top: 51px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can solve this issue pretty easily.  Just add `display: flex` and `flex-direction` to `#wrapper`.  Then, inside of a media query, add `order: 0` to `.header_section` and `order: -1` to `.navigation_menu`.  This will switch those two around, but leave everything else in the order it was before.

You should be able to just add this to your css:

```
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:640px) {
  .header_section {
    order: 0;
  }
  .navigation_menu {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

```js
var el = document.getElementById("toggle");
el.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
  menu.classList.toggle("show")
}, false);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header,
nav ul {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

header {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#logo {
  width: 40%;
}

.awards {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: 40%
}

#award1 {
  width: 25%
}

#award2 {
  width: 75%;
}

nav {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e3f5ab 0%, #99ca00 100%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 3rem;
}

#toggle {
  display: none;
  align-self: flex-end;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  margin: .5rem 1rem;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

li {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  height: 3rem;
  line-height: 3rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #02006d;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.caret {
  font-size: .6rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width:700px) {
  #logo {
    width: 70%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  #award1 {
    display: none;
  }
  #award2 {
    display: none;
  }
  header {
    order: 0;
    display: block;
  }
  nav {
    order: -1;
  }
  #toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  #toggle img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
  
  nav ul.show {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  nav ul li {
    width: 100vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <img id="logo" src="http://www.capcar.com.au/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/LOGO-FOR-WEB23.png" />
    <div class="awards">
      <img id="award1" src="http://www.capcar.com.au/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/HIA_Logo1.png" alt="" />
      <img id="award2" src="http://www.capcar.com.au/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/MBA_Logo.png" alt="" />
    </div>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <button id="toggle"><img src="http://www.tax-consulting-group-san-diego.com/images/taxes-menu-icon.png" alt="" /></button>
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Projects <span class="caret">&#9660;</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

A [simple clean demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwBVJW), and a [demo with your site](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvKMma?editors=110) (codepen doesn't like your site, so the header looks weird, but I can't get all the css to load properly—hence the simple demo).

For more info on flexbox here's a [snippet from css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and the [support tables](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the flex property to build your menus. I have great success with this feature and it allows for a number of simple order methods via CSS and media queries. Try [CSS-Tricks.com as a reference](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)